# Log log4net numeric level value

Tags: log4net

I would like to log the numeric value corresponding to the log level when using log4net. That is, right now I am logging to database with the following command text:

```xml
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />

   <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

I would like to change the string value of the logging level to the numeric. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not test this but the following should work.

You can create your own converter like this:

```cs
sealed class NumericLevelPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter 
{
    override protected void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        // maybe you need to call ToString() on the value property
        writer.Write( loggingEvent.Level.Value ); 
    }
}
```

and in the configuration file:

```xml
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <converter>
        <name value="levelId" />
        <type value="YourNamespace.NumericLevelPatternConverter" />
    </converter>
    <conversionPattern value="%levelId" />
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfect. The only problem is that I would like to put the Converter class in another project (so I don't have to make a converter class for every project in the solution). When I try to do this I get a System.TypeLoadException. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: yes, specify the type with assemlby i.e. something like: YourNamespace.YourType, YourAssembly. If this still does not work you need to use the fully qualified name includes Version, Culture and PublicKey Token